# How to pass windows authentication credentials to different site on the same server

Tags: iis, iframe, cookies, local-storage, windows-authentication

I have an asp.net mvc web application on IIS server(MySERVER). On one of the pages I use a IFrame element to display another resource(QlikView Dashboard) which is also servered up from the same IIS server(MySERVER). The IFrame element that I use on the first site is as follows.

```
<div id="reportFrameDev">
    <iframe id="reportFrame" src="http://MySERVER/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=Ashwini/CMS.qvw&host=QVS@bh-vmapp01" frameborder="0" height="800" , width="100%"> </iframe>
</div>
```

The first site has Forms Auth. But this second site (MySERVER/QvAJAXZfc/) is configured for windows authentication (which I dont want to change) and this bothers users with a windows authentication pop-up windows. I want to avoid this pop-up without altering the windows Authentication mechanism(on the second site). So I am exploring different ways to pass on windows credentials from my first site to send one(both on the same server - MySERVER) securly. The best I guess would be on the server side code itself. If not what are the ways using cookies, What about local storage? From the browser can this be done **Securely**?

Comment: It sounds like this is an internal server on an intranet. Would it be possible to make the first application to use windows authentication?  This would be the most secure setup.

Comment: I am in the same situation... ever figure anything out?